# how to access to specific value in nested dict of context, in Django 2 template?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, templates

I'd like to render a variable in a Django template, and this variable is inside a dict, in another dict.
How could I do?  Below an example.

views.js>

```
....(view)
dicIn = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}
dicOut = { 'a': None, 'b': dicIn }
context={
  res: dicOut
}
 return render_to_response('app/results.html', context)
....
```

Here is what I'd like to do
results.html>

```
<ul class="list-group">
  These are {{ res.b.two }} apples.
</ul>
```

Rendered as

```
* These are 2 apples.
```

Thank you in advance ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost right, except for the fact that `context` isn't an item in the template context itself. You just need `{{ res.b.two }}`.

Comment: thank you for reply, but it was a typo, sorry. Therefor even if I call it by _res_ I'm not able to access to the deep value _two_ :/ .

Comment: I have to say you're completely right. My same example works fine, but my real code does not. Maybe because something goes wrong during pandas dataframe conversion to a dict ( df.to_dict() ). In fact I obtain nothing when I call a value deeper than 2 levels.