# How to access dictionary element from html?

Tags: python, html, django, dictionary

I have python dictionary and I wanted to access a deep field of it in html.

dictionary  -

```
dictionary = {"album":{ 
           "album_type":"single",
            "images": [
            {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273358193d702a21397291432ef",
            "width": 640
            },
            {
            "height": 300,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02358193d702a21397291432ef",
            "width": 300
            },
            {
            "height": 64,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851358193d702a21397291432ef",
            "width": 64
            }]
         }
}
```

I wanted to access the image url, I know how to do that in python like-

```
dictionary["album"]["images"][0]['url']
```

But don't know how to do it in html.

NOTE: I am using Django Framework

Comment: What do you mean by "in html" ? Are you using a python framework such as django or what ? How does your HTML code interact with python ?

Comment: There's a way to access the images field in html for example - {{album.images}} but images also contains three field [height, url, width]. I think there should be a way to do that. if images field only contains url then it would be easy ({{album.images.url}}). I am working in django framework that's how they connected.

Comment: Writing things inside an HTML file does not mean that your are doing something "in HTML". You are actually (and likely) doing things in [Jinja2](https://codeburst.io/jinja-2-explained-in-5-minutes-88548486834e).

Comment: Have you tried [`{{ dictionary.album.images.0.url }}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290244/how-to-access-to-specific-value-in-nested-dict-of-context-in-django-2-template) ?

Comment: {{dictionary.album.images.0.url}}, it works thanks man